# Drawing Euler Angles rotational model on a 2d image

Tags: c++, opencv, euler-angles

I'm currently attempting to draw a 3d representation of euler angles within a 2d image (no opengl or 3d graphic windows).  The image output can be similar to as below.

[image: euler angles]

Essentially I am looking for research or an algorithm which can take a Rotation Matrix or a set of Euler angles and then output them onto a 2d image, like above.  This will be implemented in a C++ application that uses OpenCV. It will be used to output annotation information on a OpenCV window based on the state of the object.

I think I'm over thinking this because I should be able to decompose the unit vectors from a rotation matrix and then extract their x,y components and draw a line in cartesian space from (0,0).  Am i correct in this thinking?

EDIT: I'm looking for an Orthographic Projection.  You can assume the image above has the correct camera/viewing angle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

EDIT: The example source code can now be found in my repo. 
Header: https://bitbucket.org/jluzwick/tennisspindetector/src/6261524425e8d80772a58fdda76921edb53b4d18/include/projection_matrix.h?at=master

Class Definitions: https://bitbucket.org/jluzwick/tennisspindetector/src/6261524425e8d80772a58fdda76921edb53b4d18/src/projection_matrix.cpp?at=master

It's not the best code but it works and shows the steps necessary to get the projection matrix described in the accepted answer.

Also here is a youtube vid of the projection matrix in action (along with scale and translation added): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSgTFBFb_68

Comment: Are you looking for an orthographic projection or for a perspective projection?

Comment: orthographic.  I'm looking for a simple way to place a 3d representation of euler angles onto a 2d plane.  Thanks, I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my two cents. Hope it helps.

If I understand correctly, you want to rotate *3D* system of coordinates and then project it orthogonally onto a given *2D* plane (*2D* plane is defined with respect to the original, unrotated *3D* system of coordinates).

"Rotating and projecting *3D* system of coordinates" is "rotating three *3D* basis vectors and projecting them orthogonally onto a *2D* plane so they become *2D* vectors with respect to *2D* basis of the plane". Let the original *3D* vectors be unprimed and the resulting *2D* vectors be primed. Let **{e1, e2, e3} = {e1..3}** be *3D* orthonormal basis (which is given), and **{e1', e2'} = {e1..2'}** be *2D* orthonormal basis (which we have to define). Essentially, we need to find such operator **PR** that **PR * v = v'**.

While we can talk a lot about linear algebra, operators and matrix representation, it'd be too long of a post. It'll suffice to say that :

1. For both *3D* rotation and *3D->2D* projection operators there are real matrix representations (linear transformations; *2D* is subspace of *3D*).
2. These are two transformations applied consequently, i.e. **PR * v = P * R * v = v'**, so we need to find rotation matrix **R** and projection matrix **P**. Clearly, after we rotated **v** using **R**, we can project the result vector **vR** using **P**.
3. You have the rotation matrix **R** already, so we consider it is a given *3x3* matrix. So for simplicity we will talk about projecting vector **vR = R * v**.
4. Projection matrix **P** is a *2x3* matrix with *i*-th column being a projection of *i*-th *3D* basis vector **ei** onto **{e1..2'}** basis.

Let's find **P** projection matrix such as a *3D* vector **vR** is linearly transformed into *2D* vector **v'** on a *2D* plane with an orthonormal basis **{e1..2'}**.

A *2D* plane can be easily defined by a vector normal to it. For example, from the figures in the OP, it seems that our *2D* plane (the plane of the paper) has normal unit vector **n = *1/sqrt(3)* * ( 1, 1, 1 )**. We need to find a *2D* basis in the *2D* plane defined by this **n**. Since any two linearly independent vectors lying in our *2D* plane would form such basis, here are infinite number of such basis. From the problem's geometry and for the sake of simplicity, let's impose two additional conditions: first, the basis should be orthonormal; second, should be visually appealing (although, this is somewhat a subjective condition). As it can be easily seen, such basis is formed trivially in the primed system by setting **e1' = ( 1, 0 )' = *x'***-axis (horizontal, positive direction from left to right) and **e2' = ( 0, 1 )' = *y'***-axis (vertical, positive direction from bottom to top).

Let's now find this **{e1', e2'}** *2D* basis in **{e1..3}** *3D* basis.

1. Let's denote **e1'** and **e2'** as **e1"** and **e2"** in the original basis. Noting that in our case **e1"** has no **e3**-component (***z***-component), and using the fact that **n *dot* e1" = 0**, we get that **e1' = ( 1, 0 )' -> e1" = ( -1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2), 0 )** in the **{e1..3}** basis. Here, ***dot*** denotes dot-product.
2. Then **e2" = n *cross* e1" = ( -1/sqrt(6), -1/sqrt(6), 2/sqrt(6) )**. Here, ***cross*** denotes cross-product.

The *2x3* projection matrix **P** for the *2D* plane defined by **n = *1/sqrt(3)* * ( 1, 1, 1 )** is then given by:

```
( -1/sqrt(2)    1/sqrt(2)        0     )
( -1/sqrt(6)   -1/sqrt(6)    2/sqrt(6) )
```

where first, second and third columns are transformed **{e1..3}** *3D* basis onto our *2D* basis **{e1..2'}**, i.e. **e1 = ( 1, 0, 0 )** from *3D* basis has coordinates **( -1/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(6) )** in our *2D* basis, and so on.

To verify the result we can check few obvious cases:

1. **n** is orthogonal to our *2D* plane, so there should be no projection. Indeed, **P * n = P * ( 1, 1, 1 ) = 0**.
2. **e1**, **e2** and **e3** should be transformed into their representation in **{e1..2'}**, namely corresponding column in **P** matrix. Indeed, **P * e1 = P * ( 1, 0 ,0 ) = ( -1/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(6) )** and so on.

To finalize the problem. We now constructed a projection matrix **P** from *3D* into *2D* for an arbitrarily chosen *2D* plane. We now can project any vector, previously rotated by rotation matrix **R**, onto this plane. For example, rotated original basis **{R * e1, R * e2, R * e3}**. Moreover, *we can multiply given* **P** *and* **R** *to get a rotation-projection transformation matrix* **PR = P * R**.

P.S. C++ implementation is left as a homework exercise ;).

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is what I needed to get started.  I'm going to implement this soon and update my question with my implementation.  Thanks Petr!

Comment: Note:  I forgot to leave out that I'm going to need it scale a little, depending on how large I want to draw the x,y,z axis and I will also need to translate it, which isn't a bit deal either.  Just some constant multiplication and addition.  I'll update the answer later with my additional requirements when I put the code in.

Comment: @jluzwick You are welcome. Translation will be just adding a vector (either _3D_ or _2D_ to translate corresponding origin (since it's an orthogonal projection, not a perspective one), depending how you want to handle it). If scaling is isotropic then you just need to multiply by a scalar at any moment. If it's anisotropic than you have to operate with a corresponding diagonal matrix on initial _3D_ vector (but I don't think you mean to introduce anisotropy). It was an interesting question. Looking forward to see how it will end up looking.

Answer (score 0):

The rotation matrix will be easy to display,

A Rotation matrix can be constructed by using a normal, binormal and tangent.

You should be able to get them back out as follows:-

```
Bi-Normal (y') : matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1], matrix[0][2]
Normal    (z') : matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1], matrix[1][2]
Tangent   (x') : matrix[2][0], matrix[2][1], matrix[2][2]
```

Using a perspective transform you can the add perspective (x,y) = (x/z, y/z)

To acheive an orthographic project similar to that shown you will need to multiply by another fixed rotation matrix to move to the "camera" view (45° right and then up)

You can then multiply your end points x(1,0,0),y(0,1,0),z(0,0,1) and center(0,0,0) by the final matrix, use only the x,y coordinates.

center should always transform to 0,0,0

You can then scale these values to draw to you 2D canvas.